# jQuery serialize() on ajax loaded form not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have some issues with serialize() on a ajax loaded form.

**The jQuery code:**

```
$(document).on("submit", this.id, function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var frm     = e.target.id;
  var frmData = $("#"+frm).serialize();
  console.log(frm);
  console.log(frmData);
});
```

**Console output:**

1. loginForm
2. (empty text)

**The form itself (bootstrap):**

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="logintab">
  <div class="well">
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="loginForm">
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">E-mail adres</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="email" id="inputEmail" value="info@domainname.com" placeholder="E-mail adres" data-validation-email-message="Not a valid e-mail address"  required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="password" id="inputPassword" value="test" placeholder="Wachtwoord" data-validation-required-message="Not a valid password"  required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <button type="submit" class="btn submitbtn"><i class="icon-signin"></i> Inloggen</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `ajax-loaded-form`, does that mean you are getting the `html` using `ajax` and then inserting that `html` into the page?

Comment: Why don't you try $(e.target).serialize() instead? Or something like $("#loginForm").submit(function(e) { console.log( $(this).serialize() ); });

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Form elements needs to have a name and a value to be serialized, your elements does not have a name. If you add a name :

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" ......
```

it works just fine:

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/asy9u/)